# Django Admin: Executing a command after the objects have been saved without post_save signal

Tags: django, admin

I have some code that needs to be executed after new/changed data has been saved but it is not dependent on any one particular change. Thus, I'd rather not have it executed for every single change as would be the case using the `post_save` signal. The `save_model` method, however, executes too early for my purpose.

Is there any other way to hook into the admin's save process *after* the changes have been persisted to the database except for the `post_save` signal?

Answer (score 0):

The save method is called after new and update.

```
class YourModel(Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # Here do what you want your data are in the db
```

Comment: It's weird, it seems like this should work. However, it somehow is still too early. What my code does is notify another application which in turn polls the database for the new data. For some reason, the other application still does not see the new data if it is notified from this method.